# Is there a way to hold a selection of multiple files path in bash ? Or any entries in an ouput at all?

Tags: bash, select, filter, grep

Every time I make a list of files with ls or find, I have to use some heavy pattern matchin + redirection to a temporary file to get only the files I want and then reuse the list in the command line (eg: to move them, renome then, etc).

Is there way to either :

- scan a directory and get a list of the stuff there is, and pick what we want ([in a way like SCM breeze does for git](https://github.com/ndbroadbent/scm_breeze)), so we can later pipe the selection to any command ?
- or just filter any output to do this (like a manual grep) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of files and save them in a variable:

```
list=*.txt
```

for example.  You can then just use `$list` when you need the files, although that won't work if you have embedded whitespace in any of the filenames (there are ways around that using an array).

If your filenames are in a file and you want them in a variable, just:

```
read list < filename
```

Not sure why you would want to pipe those into a command, but if you need it:

```
echo *.txt|some_command
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find all your want in this [BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

This is one example:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
  some command "$file"
done < <(find . -type f -name '*.mp3' -print0)
```

And another one:

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in ./**/*.mp3; do
  some command "$file"
done
```